# Show Logout if user is already logged in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to show the `<router-link>` of Logout in Navbar if only user is logged in. I can do it but only if i refresh the page. Here is what i'm talking about, After I logged in `<router-link>` of Logout won't show up unless I refresh the page, then after logged out `<router-link>` won't be disappeared unless I refresh the page.

How can I fix it?

This is what I have tried:

```
// inside vuex
getters: {
    loggedIn(state) {
      return state.accessToken != null;
    },
},

// Navbar.vue
<template>
  <v-app-bar app color="primary" height="80">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Navbar</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <router-link v-show="showLogout" to="/logout"> Logout </router-link
        >
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  data() {
    return {
      showLogout: false,
    };
  },
  created() {
    if (this.$store.getters.loggedIn) {
      this.showLogout = true;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

I can provide more if you need more info.

Thanks

Comment: I dont have experience with Vue.js but did they have conditional rendering https://en.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a right way to do this.
You don't need declare the property showLogout in your data component, becouse you'll use directlly as computed property, this value is always updated, getter is for this, to return the updated value ever when to accessed. In this way you app will be more powerfull, and you get the ability to see the amazing power of reactive in action. =)

Try with some code like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
  logged: false,
  accessToken: false,
})

export const mutations = {
  set_login(state) {
    state.logged = !state.logged
  },
}

export const actions = {
  setLogin({ commit }) {
    commit('set_login')
  },
}

export const getters = {
  loggedIn(state) {
    return state.logged || false
  },
}


<template>
  <v-app-bar app color="primary" height="80">
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">Navbar</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <button v-if="loggedIn" @click="setLogin()">Logout</button>
        <button v-else @click="setLogin()">Login</button>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      loggedIn: 'loggedIn',
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      setLogin: 'setLogin',
    }),
  },
}
</script>
```